# How to remove duplicate SQL rows based off 1 column by comparing 2 different date columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that joins multiple tables/views and displays rows that are identified by a column named VIN. I want to only show the VIN one time based off of the most recent date from 2 different date fields (OPEN DATE & INVOICE DATE) IF both dates have a Value.

If Invoice Date is Null, show the row that has the most recent Open Date for that VIN.  For example, if I have 3 rows for VIN='XY123456' and

Row 1 shows Open Date  3/1/2019 and Invoice Date NULL, and

Row 2 shows Open Date 3/15/2019 and Invoice Date 3/28/2019, and

Row 3 shows Open Date 4/1/2019 and Invoice Date 4/5/2019,

I want to return Row 1 since the Invoice Date is NULL and it is the most recent Open Date for that VIN.

Had there been an Invoice Date for Row 1, we would return the row with the most recent date from either date column.

I have tried ELSE clause and COALASCE without success.  I also tried doing a subquery to use MAXDATE.

```
SELECT RO.[RepairOrderID]
      ,RO.[CompanyName]
      ,CUS.CustomerKey
      ,UN.UnitNumber AS 'UNIT #'
      ,ISNULL(UC.[Tag #],'') AS 'S #'
      ,UN.Year
      ,UN.Make
      ,UN.Model
      ,UN.VIN
      ,ROS.[RepairOrderStatus] AS 'STATUS'
      ,RO.RepairOrderNumber AS 'RO #'
      ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),DATEPART(month, RO.[OpenDate])) 
       + '/'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),DATEPART(DAY, RO.[OpenDate])) 
       + '/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),DATEPART(YEAR, RO.[OpenDate])) 
         'OPEN DATE'
     ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),DATEPART(month, ROI.InvoiceDate)) 
       + '/'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),DATEPART(DAY, ROI.InvoiceDate)) 
       + '/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),DATEPART(YEAR, ROI.InvoiceDate)) 
         'INVOICE DATE'
  FROM [ProfitMaster].[dbo].[RepairOrder] RO with (nolock)
  INNER JOIN [ProfitMaster].[dbo].[vwAC_SSR_Customer] CUS with (nolock)
  ON CUS.CustomerID = RO.CustomerID
  INNER JOIN [ProfitMaster].[dbo].[RepairOrderStatus] ROS with (nolock)
  ON ROS.RepairOrderStatusID = RO.RepairOrderStatusID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [ProfitMaster].[dbo].[RepairOrderInvoice] ROI with (nolock)
  ON ROI.RepairOrderID = RO.RepairOrderID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [ProfitMaster].[dbo].[vwSR_SSR_Unit] UN with (nolock)
  ON UN.UnitInventoryID = RO.UnitInventoryID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [ProfitMaster].[dbo].[vwSR_SSR_UnitCharacteristics] UC with (nolock)
  ON UC.UnitInventoryID = Ro.UnitInventoryID
  WHERE ((ROS.RepairOrderStatus IN ('OPEN')
  OR (ROS.RepairOrderStatus = 'QUOTE' AND RO.OpenDate >= (getDate()- 90)))
  OR (ROS.RepairOrderStatus = 'INVOICED' AND ROI.InvoiceDate > '2019-01-01 00:00:00.000'))
  AND (CUS.InternalAccount = '0' AND CUS.InternalLRCustomer = '0')
```

Results Sample:

[image]

Comment: If you add the sample data( not an image) and desired output( not an image) you will help to people who wants to help you and it will clarify what you want.

Comment: Seems you want to calculate a row_number like this `Row_Number()
Over (PARTITION BY VIN 
      ORDER BY CASE WHEN InvoiceDate IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, OpenDate DESC)`

Comment: @StepUp - The picture is fine for sample results.  Not sure why that would matter.

Comment: @dnoeth - thank you for the suggestion.  I tried, but it doesnt seem to be working correctly.  It isnt taking the highest date out of both dates for all rows with the same VIN.

Comment: Then add sample data (DDL & Inserts) covering all possible combinations and expected result (with explanation)

Comment: Based on your narrative you need another CASE in ORDER BY: `Row_Number()
Over (PARTITION BY VIN 
      ORDER BY CASE WHEN InvoiceDate IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
               CASE WHEN InvoiceDate > OpenDate THEN InvoiceDate ELSE OpenDate END DESC)
`

Comment: @dnoeth why not post your answer as an answer, so that the question can be closed properly?

Comment: @TabAlleman: It was just a guess, only the OP knows if it's correct :-)

Comment: How do I add sample data?  Sorry, I am new to this.